# How do I activate co-op?

Tags: starfox-zero

On the box for Star Fox Zero, it says that I can play co-op with the Wii U gamepad and another controller, but when I select a level in story mode, it just starts the level without asking anything about player 2.  Moving the control stick on the second controller does nothing and I don't see any options in the pause menu about it.

We read the in-game manual using the home screen, but it just says to select co-op play from the level select screen!  Every level I start doesn't prompt me about co-op.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After starting the level, you need to open the menu and back out to the level select screen again. Selecting the level from there will give you the option to start co-op play by pressing X. For some reason, you aren't presented this option in the normal course of events, so you have to do this for every single level you start.